# Laravel Copy record and duplicate with User IDs

Tags: laravel

How can i copy a record and save it with a different value for 1 or more field? for example 
I have a table(post table) with following columns -  ID | User ID | Post Title | Post Type 
And User Table(user) with following columns - ID | Username | Email | Password

What i need to do is - When the saving post data needs to be duplicate with user ids

For example - In user table there is 10 users and when i save the post it should be duplicate for all ten user id

```
   ID | User ID | Post Title | Post Type
   1  | 1       | Test Post  | Public   
   2  | 2       | Test Post  | Public 
   3  | 3       | Test Post  | Public 
   4  | 4       | Test Post  | Public 
   5  | 5       | Test Post  | Public 
   6  | 6       | Test Post  | Public 
   7  | 7       | Test Post  | Public 
   8  | 8       | Test Post  | Public
```

[image]

Comment: in which table you want to add data and which data are you want to duplicate, i didn't understand your question , please explain `When the saving post data needs to be duplicate with user ids` this in detail

Comment: @SaurabhMistry I updated with the screenshot

Comment: You can use `replicate` on the model instance.

Comment: @Fed for this situation, why not you are using `Many to Many` relationship here.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you can do this using model replication. Like

```
$post = Post::find(12892);         //change with your id.


// get all the users.

$users = User::all();

foreach($users as $user){
    $newPost = $post->replicate();
    $newPost->user_id = $user->id;

    // save post.
    $newPost->save();
}
```